# cte tsql using variable

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a table function that comprises some CTE tables eventually rolling up to a select statement that is returned. Within one of the CTE tables, I use a @variable. It is the same @variable that I declare for the function. When I try to save the function, I get this error:

```
Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Parameters were not supplied for the function 'forecast_baseline'.
```

Is there a problem with using a @variable inside a CTE table? I can provide the code but it seems to not be passing the function @variable to the CTE table so the compiler doesn't like it.

```
ALTER function [eo].[forecast_baseline] (@monthkey as char(6)) 
  returns @results table(
  [billing_date] date,
  [year] int,
  [type] varchar(max),
  [dollars] float,
  [units] float,
  [CC] int,
  [offering] varchar(max),
  [IntegratedReleasePlanNm] varchar(max),
  [ProjectId] varchar(max),
  [ProjectNm]  varchar(max),
  [ModelEstimateId] varchar(max),
  [query] varchar(max),
  [ItemGroupId]  varchar(max),
  CashflowType varchar(12),
  plotdate datetime
  )
  as
  begin
    declare @StartTime datetime = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(getdate())-1),getdate()),101))
    declare @EndTime datetime = DATEADD(year, +5, @StartTime)
    declare @Interval int = 1;

    WITH yearsinmonths (
      [datetimemonth], 
      [enddatetimemonth]) AS ( 
          SELECT
            @StartTime datetimemonth, 
            DATEADD(month, @Interval, @StartTime) AS enddatetimemonth
          UNION ALL
          SELECT
            EndRange, 
            DATEADD(month, @Interval, enddatetimemonth)
          FROM 
            cSequence 
          WHERE 
            DATEADD(month, @Interval, enddatetimemonth) < @EndTime
    ), 

    forecast_baseline (
      [billing_date],
      [year],
      [type],
      [dollars],
      [units],
      [CC],
      [offering],
      [IntegratedReleasePlanNm],
      [ProjectId],
      [ProjectNm],
      [ModelEstimateId],
      [query],
      [ItemGroupId],
      [CashflowType]) as (
          select 
            dateadd(month,-1,convert(date, a.CHARGE_MONTH+'01', 112))
            ,year(dateadd(month,-1,convert(date, a.CHARGE_MONTH+'01', 112)))
            ,'Baseline'
            ,sum(cast(a.CHARGE_AMOUNT as money))
            ,sum(cast (PPGUNITS as float))
            ,ORG_CC
            ,[offering]
            ,'Baseline'
            ,'baseline'
            ,'baseline'
            ,'baseline'
            ,'baseline'
            ,'N/A'
            ,'N/A'
          from 
            [sources].[feeds].[MARS2IEO_MARS_BD12_INV_LOB_EXTRACTS] a join sources.[md].[MARS_ITEMID_MAPPING] b 
              on a.offering=b.itemid 
          where 
            host_name is not null 
            and (a.org_sort_code like ('KBBFA%') or 
                a.org_sort_code like ('KBBFB%') or
                a.org_sort_code like ('KBBDD%'))
            and b.category in ('server','disk','tape')
            and cast(year(dateadd(month,-1,convert(date,     a.CHARGE_MONTH+'01', 112))) as char(4)) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,month(dateadd(month,-1,convert(date, a.CHARGE_MONTH+'01', 112)))), 2) <= @monthkey -- this is the line that throws the error
          group by 
            offering
            ,ORG_CC
            ,dateadd(month,-1,convert(date, a.CHARGE_MONTH+'01', 112))
            ,year(dateadd(month,-1,convert(date, a.CHARGE_MONTH+'01', 112)))
)

    INSERT INTO @results (
      [billing_date],
      [year],
      [type],
      [dollars],
      [units],
      [CC],
      [offering],
      [IntegratedReleasePlanNm],
      [ProjectId],
      [ProjectNm],
      [ModelEstimateId],
      [query],
      [ItemGroupId],
      [CashflowType]
      )
      select 
        * 
      from 
        forecast_baseline

    INSERT INTO @results (
      [billing_date],
      [year],
      [type],
      [dollars],
      [units],
      [CC],
      [offering],
      [IntegratedReleasePlanNm],
      [ProjectId],
      [ProjectNm],
      [ModelEstimateId],
      [query],
      [ItemGroupId],
      CashflowType
      )
      SELECT 
        b.datetimemonth
        ,year([billing_date])
        ,'Baseline'
        ,[dollars]
        ,[units]
        ,CC
        ,[offering]
        ,'Baseline'
        ,'projected'
        ,'projected'
        ,'projected'
        ,'projected'
        ,'N/A'
        ,'N/A'
      FROM 
        forecast_baseline a inner join yearsinmonths b 
          on cast(year([billing_date]) as char(4))+ RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,month([billing_date])), 2) = @monthkey
         and b.datetimemonth > [billing_date]
      return
  end
```

Comment: Yes, provide the code please

Comment: added code. the problem is in the **forecast_baseline** cte. it is looking for a parameter like it isn't recognizing the @monthkey as the parameter. I have to have the variable there because the table that this cte pulls from is too big to load the whole thing. performance would tank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you have named `CTE` as your function name. Change second `CTE` name:

```
...
 WHERE 
 DATEADD(month, @Interval, enddatetimemonth) < @EndTime
), 

forecast_baseline (
...
```

to any other name.

Also you will need to use `UNION ALL` instead of seperate 2 inserts in result table, because you have only 1 possibility to query `CTE`. You can not query `CTE` multiple times.

Comment: wow. good catch. that didn't even occur to me. it should have.... I was recursing without realizing it. Thank you so much!